# How to Deploy two websites on one domain?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, nginx, web-deployment, webdeploy

We are using front end technology as php and web server as nginx on ubuntu. Our application have a registration page for company. As soon as new company registers we create a unique sub domain for company. http://localserver.in/register and http://company.localserver.in/login.

We have done with these setup where we are able to access server with companies sub domain.

Now we are moving towards deployment where we come up with 3 different branches on git. QA, Release and Production. We have decided to keep QA and Release branch on only one AWS instance and also will have one DB. Its like 2 code base and 1 DB approach.

Now I can easily buy new domain and setup with AWS instance but that will add overhead to manage different configuration settings.

As we are creating sub domain for every company we can not point two different code base to different sub domain.

In this scenario is it really possible to handle QA and Release branch on one domain? Or we need to buy two different domains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done. Resolved with three virtual host configuration and bit changes in code.

Basically setup 2 repos under your web directory. www/qa and www/release. Add nginx configuration for qa.server.in and release.server.in. You require one more for subdomain that is *.server.in.

Now when I access qa.server.in points to code base at www/qa
When I access release.server.in points to code base at www/release

Both code base have registration and login page. Lets consider I have company registered with name client. So company home page will be company.server.in.

As soon as company logged in into qa.server.in will be redirected to client.server.in/qa. Same for release.

And yes! I achieved it.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO this is just an nginx config question — if I understand you correctly.

How does your nginx config look like? Wouldn't something like this work?

```
server {
    root /www/qa;
    server_name company1.server.in;
    include config;
}
server {
    root /www/release;
    server_name company2.server.in;
    include config;
}
server {
    root /www/qa;
    server_name company3.server.in;
    include config;
}
...
```

Comment: This is not what I meant. I already configured nginx settings for QA.server.in (/www/qa) and release.server.in (/www/release). These two are different code base. Both have registration page. As soon as any comapny registers we create subdomain for company. For eg if company ABC registers on qa.server.in company url will become abc.server.in. Now i need a structure like abc.qa.server.in or abc.release.server.in. I hope it will give you more understanding.